# Hide month placeholder in FSCalender objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am implementing FSCalender and i want to hide month placeholder but not get that class name or code.Can anyone help me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pleae post image for what you want to hide.

Comment: Thanks Paul  for reply ,ok

Comment: As you can see in image their is next and previous arrow behind this their is placeholder i want to hide that.

Comment: @VidehJaiswal Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide month placeholder but If you can set white color of Header Title then it will be not visible.

### Default Color Blue

[image: Default Color Blue]

### Change color of Header title

[image: White Color]

## Update

You can use `HidePlaceholderViewController class` the place holder will remove.

For reference [download latest source code](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar) and check Hide Placeholder class.

[image]

Comment: but it removes the month name may 2018 in your image  also

Comment: I don't understand your replay

Comment: I means placeholder and title of Month Name both are hide.

Comment: Yes both are hide

Comment: I think you are taking about this line   calendar.placeholderType = FSCalendarPlaceholderTypeNone; i have used but only hide date placeholder not month

Comment: Yes, and you can hide month with white color.

Answer (score 0):

**Add this line**

```
calendarView.appearance.headerMinimumDissolvedAlpha = 0
```